# How to iterate over JSON array with jq?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm building a script to download all CodeCommit repositories at once.

```sh
REPOS=$(aws codecommit list-repositories)

echo $REPOS | jq -r '.[]' | while read name ; do
    git clone XXX
done
```

In first line I get all repos JSON like this:

```json
[
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_a",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_b",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_c",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_d",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  }
]
```

I need simple iterate this json, to get attributes repositoryName and execute git clone for each repository.

But in this example the command `jq -r '.[]'` don't works.... This return the entire json on each repeat.

Comment: Sounds like you want `.[][]` to go down an additional nesting layer.

Comment: To be clear, we can't reproduce your bug unless you give us the original output from `aws codecommit list-repositories`. A better [mre] would, instead of running a tool that only you can run and get your output, maybe hardcode sample data that's reflective of the real format (so f/e, you can define a `aws` function that writes data in the same format to its stdout).

Comment: Also, `echo $REPOS |` is itself buggy. See [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` prints something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else) -- you should _always_ quote your expansions, as in, `echo "$REPOS" | ...`

Answer (score 26):

```
echo "$REPOS" | jq '.[].repositoryName' | while read -r repo; do echo "do something with $repo"; done
```

Output:

```
do something with "repo_a"
do something with "repo_b"
do something with "repo_c"
do something with "repo_d"
```

Or without quotes:

```
echo "$REPOS" | jq -r '.[].repositoryName' | while read -r repo; do echo "do something with $repo"; done
```

Output:

```
do something with repo_a
do something with repo_b
do something with repo_c
do something with repo_d
```

Comment: `xargs -L1` would be useful too.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, I don't know exactly what else he's up to.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to iterate over JSON values instead of a single field value, you can use the `-c` option so you end up with one JSON element per line:

```
repositories='{
  "repositories": [
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_a",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_b",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_c",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_d",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  }
]
}'
```

```bash
while read repository
do
  name=$(echo "$repository" | jq -r .repositoryName)
  id=$(echo "$repository" | jq -r .repositoryId)

  echo "${id}=${name}"
done < <(echo "$repositories" | jq -c '.repositories[]')
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem..... this command:

```
REPOS=$(aws codecommit list-repositories)
```

Returns a json like this:

```
{
  "repositories": [
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_a",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_b",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_c",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  },
  {
    "repositoryName": "repo_d",
    "repositoryId": "XXXXXX"
  }
]
}
```

I wasn't considering the 'repositories' field in jq.....

This script works fine now:

```
REPOS=$(aws codecommit list-repositories)

echo $REPOS | jq -r '.repositories[].repositoryName' | while read name ; do
    git clone ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/$name
done
```

Thank you for support.
Have a good day :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert to scalar values:

```
#!/bin/bash

D='[
{ "name": "first", "is_disabled": false, "scheme": "https", "value": 30 },
{ "name": "second", "is_disabled": true, "scheme": "https", "value": 118 },
{ "name": "third", "is_disabled": false, "scheme": "https", "value": 93 }
]'

LEN=$( echo "$D" | jq '. | length' )

echo "got $LEN elements"
for (( i=0; i<$LEN; i++ )) ; do
        echo "Element $i:"
        echo "$D" | jq ".[$i]"
done
```

But it's not very efficient.

A quick google turned up [this solution](https://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/bash-for-loop-over-json-array-using-jq/index.html):

```
sample='[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]'
for row in $(echo "${sample}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
    _jq() {
     echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
    }
   echo $(_jq '.')
done
```